# Duplicate image multiple times while enlarging each subsequent duplicate

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have to print images for jewelry molds.

I select a 0.5 cm image and duplicate it, enlarging it 2 mm each time until I reach 5 cm.

Expected result:
[image]

Comment: If you start at 0.5cm and increase the width or height in 0.2cm increments, you cannot get an image that has a 5cm width or height, as applicable.

Comment: Q: How could we automate this task?  A: Use macros.  Q: I don't know how to use macros.  A: This sounds like a good opportunity to learn, doesn't it? Specifically, it sounds like maybe Word's [Record macro](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-or-run-a-macro-c6b99036-905c-49a6-818a-dfb98b7c3c9c) might be what you're looking for.  Click on the link, or look here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9v6d_5SVB8

Answer (score 0):

The following macro takes the selected inlineshape, formats its width to 0.5cm, then replicates it, incrementing the width in 0.25cm increments until a 5cm width is reached. You can edit the code to work with the image heights instead, if that's what you prefer.

```
Sub PicDemo()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim i As Long, iShp As InlineShape, Rng As Range
  With Selection
    Set iShp = .InlineShapes(1): Set Rng = .Range
    With iShp
      .LockAspectRatio = True
      .Width = CentimetersToPoints(0.5)
    End With
    For i = 3 To 20
      With Rng
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        .FormattedText = iShp.Range.FormattedText
        .InlineShapes(1).Width = CentimetersToPoints(0.25 * i)
      End With
    Next
  End With
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

For PC macro installation & usage instructions, see: http://www.gmayor.com/installing_macro.htm

For Mac macro installation & usage instructions, see: http://word.mvps.org/Mac/InstallMacro.html

In either case, you should be able to simply copy/paste the code from here into the VBE, with no need to retype anything.

Comment: Good suggestion.  But I honestly think the OP might be better off with "record macro", rather than typing in (and perhaps trying to debug/troubleshoot) a VBA script.  Hopefully she'll be motivated to try at least one of the options, and post back how it works for her.

Comment: Given that the macro recorder is about as smart as a box of rocks, I doubt anyone would find your suggestion to use it for such a task particularly helpful. The code produced would be quite verbose and inefficient - as well you should know.

Comment: And now, how can I learn to do the same things? Must I study informatics or something similar?

Comment: You would need to learn VBA coding. FWIW, I've never done a VBA coding course - it's all been self-taught (with lots of studying & adapting code I've found on-line).

Comment: It worked perfectly. I love you.